# Add Nofollow to all Outgoing links in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, seo

is there any easy way to add nofollow to all outgoing links in magento?

I mean a code to automatically add nofollow to all outgoing links.

Thank you.

Comment: From which locations, you can have those links entered in system, CMS pages, product attributes, phtml files or anything else ?

Comment: If these links are being shown from template files, then I don't think there would be any automated way to have the nofollow for all of them. May be if you can show an example, I can try to suggest some work around.

Answer (score 1):

There is an event in `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front` for modifying output *after* the app generates it but *before* it is sent to the browser:

```
public function dispatch()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    //StackExchange snip...

    // This event gives possibility to launch something before sending output (allow cookie setting)
    Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_front_send_response_before', array('front'=>$this));

    $this->getResponse()->sendResponse();

    //StackExchange snip...
}
```

You can use regex to match outbound links and add `rel="nofollow"`.